# Passing SQLite3 database pointer to a Function having a sqlite3_close(db) gets a 21 error - bad parameter or other API issue

Tags: c++, function, sqlite

My goal is to have a successful SQLite3 close after an open from functions I created. 
I expected the close to return a code of zero.

I'm passing the SQLite3 *db pointer after a successful open to a function of my  
construction having an  `rc = sqlite3_close(db)`. Seems in the act of passing the   
db pointer something is lost and the close errors out. As a design feature I intend  
to have many functions built around SQLite's db call functions so getting just a  
simple open and close to work helps me in the future. This may just be a  
miss-understanding on how to pass a pointer to a function.

**The errors generated after code run:**

```
Return code: 0 |Error code: 0 |Error message: not an error |Message: Database open success
New message -->Return code: 0 |Message: Database close success
Old message -->Return code: 21 |Error code: 21 |Error message: bad parameter or other API misuse |Message: Database close failed
```

**My code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sqlite3.h>
using namespace std;

// Function prototypes
int openDB(sqlite3**, string); // Mod - Added additional *
int closeDB(sqlite3**); // Mod - Added additional *


int main()
{    
    **// Open database**
    sqlite3 *db;
    string errmsg;
    int rc;
    string dbStr = "/home/steven/sparks-robotics/data/myDB.db";
    const char* database = dbStr.c_str();
    rc = openDB(&db,database); // Mod - Added &
    if (rc != EXIT_SUCCESS) {return EXIT_FAILURE;}

    **// Close database**
    rc = closeDB(&db); // Mod - Added &
    if (rc != EXIT_SUCCESS) {return EXIT_FAILURE;}

return 0;
};

int openDB(sqlite3 **db, string dbStr) { // Mod - Added *
    int rc;         // SQLite return code
    const char* em; // SQLite error message 
    int ec;         // SQLite error code
    
    string errmsg;
    const char* database = dbStr.c_str();
    rc = sqlite3_open_v2(database, &*db, SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY, NULL); // Mod - Added *
    errmsg = "Database open success";
    ec = sqlite3_errcode(*db); // Mod - Added *
    em = sqlite3_errmsg(*db);  // Mod - Added *
    if(rc != SQLITE_OK) {errmsg = "Database open failed";}
    cout << "Return code: " << rc <<" |Error code: " << ec << " |Error message: " << em << " |Message: " + errmsg << endl;
    return rc;
};

int closeDB(sqlite3 **db) { // Mod - Added *
    int rc;         // SQLite return code
    //const char* em; // SQLite error message // Mod - Deleted
    //int ec;         // SQLite error code // Mod - Deleted

    string errmsg;
    rc = sqlite3_close(*db); // Mod - Added *
    errmsg = "Database close success";
    //ec = sqlite3_errcode(*db); // Mod - deleted, db already closed
    //em = sqlite3_errmsg(*db);  // Mod - deleted, db already closed
    if(rc != SQLITE_OK) {errmsg = "Database close failed";}
    //cout << "Return code: " << rc <<" |Error code: " << ec << " |Error message: " << em << " |Message: " + errmsg << endl; 
    cout << "Return code: " << rc << " |Message: " + errmsg << endl;  
    return rc;
};
```

Comment: If you want the implicit assignment to `db` in `openDB` to show up in the `db` variable in `main`, you need to either change the type to `sqlite3 *&db`, or change the type to `sqlite3 **db` and pass `&db`.

Comment: If a SQLite API fails, the error code is returned in your `rc` variable. You don't have to call `sqlite3_errcode` to get the error.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield . I noticed in a few cases where they were different, and I didn't understand why. I'll keep both until I feel more comfortable with SQLite, then just use the return code. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Botje I've tried to use you suggestion but I can't seem to get the code to compile when making the changes. My understanding of pointer syntax in this case is lacking. What does "implicit" assignment mean? How does this keep the database handle available for my other functions? Doesn't the (db) from the open get propagated to the rc = closeDB(db); statment in main?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment, changes to `db` in `openDB` do not show up in the variable `db` in `main`. There are two important things to understand:

1. Pointer variables have an address like any other variable, but their value is *also* an address.
2. C++ defaults to "pass by value"

I will explain the problem by interpreting your code myself:

- Before the call to `openDB`, the `db` in `main` (henceforth `main_db`) has address=0xMAIN_DB and value=GARBAGE (because you failed to initialize it)
- At the start of `openDB`, `openDB_db` has address=0xOPENDB_DB (different from `main_db`) and value=GARBAGE (because C++ is pass by value)
- You call `sqlite3_open` with `&openDB_db`, so it dutifully writes a new value to address 0xOPENDB_DB. 0xMAIN_DB is untouched.

By contrast, if you change the signature of `openDB` to take a `sqlite3 *&`, `openDB_db` is a *reference* to `main_db`, which means that `openDB_db` will have the same address as `main_db`: 0xMAIN_DB. When you now pass `&openDB_db` to `sqlite3_open`, it will effectively write a pointer value into `0xMAIN_DB`, which means that `main_db` also has that pointer value.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand the theory as well as the coding now. Added modifications to the original code. Thanks again!